# iOS - UIView subclass won't rotate with device

Tags: ios, uiview, rotation

I have a custom UIView that I use to display synchronization in my device, but it won't rotate with the device when the orientation changes. 
Everything else rotates just fine, is there something I am missing to ensure my subclassed uiview will rotate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programmatically:

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
        return YES;
    }
```

add this. Hope this helps..

Or go to your Target Settings and click the directions you want it to rotate, but this will affect all your viewcontrollers.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow any of the following methods,

1-Create a class to subclass the UIView and override the shouldAutorotate in .m(implementation file). Now include this custom UIView class in your viewController to create objects.

2-Creating category for the UIView class

NOTE:- if your building app to support iOS6 then don't forget to include the methods which apply for your requirement

```
 >>>>>- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation;
 >>>>- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate;
 >>>>- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations;
 >>>>- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation;
```

Example For Category:-

```
       @interface UIView (Additions)

       @end

       @implementation UIView (Additions)

           - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
              return YES;
                    }

       @end
```